# I get this weird error whatever i do, it says that the index is not in range. any ideas?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Whatever parameters I give when I run this procedure, it always says that my index needs to be lower. For example, if I give the parameters (1,1) it says that my index is 61 and it should be in the range of 1 to 60.

Both of these tables have two columns, the first one has id_produs and id_departament, the second one has id_produs and id_comanda. Both tables have single digit numbers inserted into both columns, yet nothing works. Does anything look particularly wrong to you?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedura_6
    (v_produse_2 produs_departament.id_produs%type, v_produse_5 comanda_produs.id_produs%type )
IS 
    TYPE varray_produse_2 IS VARRAY(60) OF produs_departament.id_produs%type;
  TYPE nested_table_produse_5 IS TABLE OF comanda_produs.id_produs%type;
    varray_numar_dept varray_produse_2:=varray_produse_2();
    nested_table_numar_com nested_table_produse_5:=nested_table_produse_5();
BEGIN 
    SELECT id_produs BULK COLLECT INTO varray_numar_dept FROM produs_departament;
    SELECT id_produs BULK COLLECT INTO nested_table_numar_com FROM comanda_produs;
   
    for l_index in varray_numar_dept.FIRST..varray_numar_dept.LAST
    LOOP
        IF (v_produse_2>varray_numar_dept(l_index)) THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(varray_numar_dept(l_index));
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    
    for l_index in nested_table_numar_com.FIRST..nested_table_numar_com.LAST
    LOOP
        IF v_produse_5>nested_table_numar_com(l_index) THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nested_table_numar_com(l_index));
        END IF;
    
    END LOOP;
END procedura_6;
/

execute procedura_6(2,2);

begin
    procedura_6(3,3);
end;
/
```

Comment: How many rows are in your `produs_departament` table - seems to be more than 60, which is the limit of the varray? Why are you using a varray for one collection and a PL/SQL table for the other?

Comment: VARRAY is not generally a useful type in PL/SQL code - it's more suited to database columns. "Nested table" collections (not really nested or tables in PL/SQL code, but that's what Oracle called them) and associative arrays are less restricted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the culprit:

```
TYPE varray_produse_2 IS VARRAY(60) OF produs_departament.id_produs%type;
                                --
                                this
```

Apparently, select from the table returns more than 60 rows, whilst you reserved only 60 *places* for them. It ran OK until the limit has been reached. For the 61st row, it failed.

Enlarge it.

Answer (score 0):

How many rows does table `produs_departament` have? I suspect it has more than 60 rows and the error is caused by trying to fetch all of these into a `VARRAY(60)`.